# Why is て-form being used in 「そして罪を受けて当然な悪人が心臓麻痺で死んでいく裏で」

Tags: て-form

In

> そして罪を**受けて**当然な悪人が心臓麻痺で死んでいく裏で
>
> Therefore, true criminals who have accepted their crimes (罪を受けて) will die of heart attacks behind the scenes...

Why is a て-form verb used here, as opposed to other forms like

> そして罪を**受けた**当然な悪人が心臓麻痺で死んでいく裏で
>
> そして罪を**受ける**当然な悪人が心臓麻痺で死んでいく裏で

where both e.g. 受けた and 当然な are modifying 悪人 as 連体形? Would all 3 of these sentences be acceptable? Or is there some crucial nuance that using the て-form imbues on the sentence?

Comment: Why did you change the verb from 受ける to 受け入れる in your second and third sentences?

Comment: @aguijonazo: That was a mistake. I just corrected the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The na-adjective (also used as a noun) 当然(だ) means "natural, reasonable, deserved, inevitable" and 当然な悪人/当然の悪人 makes no sense by itself. (This is a reason your second and third sentences seem unacceptable.) In the original sentence, the verb in te-form 受けて does not directly modify 悪人 but does 当然だ, and makes up the expression 「(verb in te-form) + 当然(だ) "it is natural/reasonable/deserved to (verb)"」.

As another point, 罪 in the expression 罪を受ける means a punishment or a reward (for a bad behavior) and not crime. 罪を受け入れる "accept one's guilt" expresses something different. 罪を受けて当然な悪人 "climinals (lit. bad people) who are deserved to get punished"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I assumed that 罪を受ける literally meant "receiving one's crimes" but was idiomatically translated into "receiving one's punishment" (since that's how we'd communicate "being punished" in English). I just made a post about this question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/101081/does-%e7%bd%aa-in-%e7%bd%aa%e3%82%92%e5%8f%97%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b-literally-mean-crimes).