# Does 罪 in 罪を受ける literally mean "crimes"?

Tags: meaning, words

Even in English, I can almost imagine someone saying

> I have received my crimes.

to be a short-hand way of saying

> What goes around comes around, and I have received the consequences for my criminal actions (of which I accept guilt).

Of course, it's way more idiomatic to just say

> I have received punishment (for my crimes).

So in Japanese, does the phrase

> 罪を受ける
>
> Receives punishment.

*literally* mean

> Receives crimes?

I ask because it's pretty confusing that 罪 usually means "crime" or "sin" but in some cases (like in this phrase) means "punishment" (a distinct but related concept). I was just curious if 罪 in all cases actually does mean "crime", but something like the above is going on.

As evidence for this, the [Wiktionary entry for 罪](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%BD%AA#Japanese) doesn't list "punishment" as an acceptable meaning of つみ (but other bilingual dictionaries [do](https://jpdb.io/vocabulary/1296680/%E7%BD%AA/%E3%81%A4%E3%81%BF?lang=english#a)).

Comment: Daijirin entry for 罪 lists "punishment" for its second definition:「①法律的・道徳的・宗教的な規範に反する行為。「―を犯す」②①に対して負うべき責任。また，それに対して科される制裁。刑罰。「―に服する」「―を償う」「―に問われる」「人の―をかぶる」」.

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/9270/meaning/m0u/

Comment: 罪を受ける doesn't sound very natural to me. 「罪を受け**入れる** 」ならいいと思いますが

Comment: I have removed the ["etymology" tag](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology), since the question doesn't actually ask about the origins or development of the term. As what seems like a more-fitting replacement, I have added the ["meaning" tag](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I find it weird, too, and from what I gathered, most contemporary speakers don't understand 罪 as "punishment".

Apparently it used to mean both things, but today many people would exclusively understand it as "crime" (so that you can say 罪を償う but not 罪に服す)